# Make ConTeXt ignore system-fonts?

Tags: fonts, context

**How can I make ConTeXt ignore my system-fonts?**

Currently, ConTeXt scans and uses all system fonts (all the files in the font folder of windows 7) first and the fonts in the ConTeXt folder second.

I want ConTeXt to ignore system fonts and only use fonts in the ConTeXt folder.

Comment: ConTeXt should not do this by default. Do you have the variable `OSFONTDIR` pointing to some of your system font directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:** ConTeXt includes system fonts by default, unless the user prevents it by two steps. (tested under windows and found similar code for MacOS, but maybe not for linux)

The environment variable `OSFONTDIR` must be set and must not be empty. It can point to the desired font directory of fonts you want to use inside ConTeXt or to an empty directory.

At least on windows-systems, the file `\fonts\conf\fonts.conf` must also be changed. An XML-entry, by default `<dir>c:/windows/fonts</dir>`, must also be changed and set to the desired location of the fonts.

**Background:** If the environment variable `OSFONTDIR` is not set or is set to an empty string, it is filled with the path to the system font directory by `mtxrun.lua`

```
do
  local osfontdir=osgetenv("OSFONTDIR")
  if osfontdir and osfontdir~="" then
  elseif osname=="windows" then
    ossetenv("OSFONTDIR","c:/windows/fonts//")
  elseif osname=="macosx" then
    ossetenv("OSFONTDIR","$HOME/Library/Fonts//;/Library/Fonts//;/System/Library/Fonts//")
  end
end
```